# Fitting new wheel with 10 speed to a bike fitted with 8 speed

Tags: road-bike, wheels, cassette

I own a Specialized Allez road bike which is 8 speed. I've just bought new wheels and want to put a 10-speed cassette on, like the previous owner. What will I have to do to the bike so that the gears work properly? Or will it be ok?

Comment: The easiest thing is to put an 8 speed cassette on the wheel.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the question. You describe it as an 8-speed bike, but also seem to be saying that the previous owner had a 10-speed cassette on it. Is that right or am I misreading?

Comment: An 8-speed cassette fits but needs a spacer at the side of the larger cog, normally 3mm. Bike stores usually have boxes with lose spacers of several sizes.

Answer (score 2):

YOU SHOULD HAVE CHECKED BEFORE BUYING THE WHEELS!

10-speed Dura-Ace is not compatible with other cassettes. You can install a 8 speed cassette on other Shimano 10-speed compatible hubs.

Edit: Reading the question again, of course you can keep the 10 speed cassette. Just replace the shifters, rear derailleur and chain with 10-speed ones and be prepared to replace front derailleur and crank if there are any problems.

Answer (score 1):

Very generally speaking, the number of cogs on the cassette needs to match the number of clicks in the shifter. If your shifter clicks through 9 gears then you need a 9 speed cassette. If it has 8 clicks as yours does then you need an 8 speed cassette. If you want to switch to 10 speeds then at a bare minimum you'd need new 10 speed shifters and quite likely a rear derailleur. The shifters and derailleurs should be from the same brand. You would also need a 10 speed chain though the brand on this doesn't really matter. This starts to get pretty expensive, pretty fast.

Answer (score 1):

So, I'm thinking that this is a bike that was originally setup with an 8-speed drive train. At some point the previous owner replaced the rear wheel with one built around a 10-speed hub. If I'm reading Sheldon Brown's page on [hub and cluster compatibility](http://www.sheldonbrown.com/speeds.html) correctly you should be able to mount an 8-speed cassette on a 10-speed free hub body.

So it seems like all that is required is to put the pieces together, perhaps with a spacer behind the cassette. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Your cheapest option is to mount the 8 speed cassette on the new wheels.  This will require a spacer but it'll get you up and running with minimal fuss and risk.

If you want to upgrade your bike to support the 10 speed cassette then you will need:

- **10 speed shifters**

...you could replace only the rear shifter, but they're usually sold as a pair and you probably want them to match.

- **10 speed chain**

...because your 8 speed chain is too wide

*You may need:*

- **10 speed derraileur**

...because yours is designed for 8 speed and might not work well with your lovely new shifters and chain.

- **Front chainrings and/or derraileur**

...if you're unlucky then you could have issues with these parts not working well with the new narrow chain.

Having budgeted for all of the above, you might find yourself considering a whole new groupset...

Comment: Theres a bit more to this. 10 speed road shifters use the same cable pull as 7,8,9 speed in Shimano. 10 speed mountain shifters use a different cable pull. So, for the rear, you have to do some matching to the shifter.

Answer (score -1):

You will probably need to get a ten speed derraileur.

Otherwise you might be able to get by with friction shifters if you've already got a thinner chain. This isn't the brightest idea because it's basically the same thing as driving a manual and requires some cursory knowledge of how the shifting mechanism works.

Comment: Welcome to [bicycles.se] @happycat. Please check out the [help] to learn about how the site works and how to write a strong answer.